# Using BOOL objects in NSMutableArray to determine cell statuses

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm using an `NSMutableArray` referenced as 'stateArray'. stateArray needs to simply hold the `BOOL` value for my cells to determine whether or not they are selected. here's my code..

stateArray in my .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *stateArray;
```

Then stateArray **is not** synthesized. It needs to be filled with `NO` throughout the array, so that when the cell becomes selected, NO can be replaced by YES. Currently this code is printing 0's for stateArray for every cell(the NSLog is in the `if (showCheckmark == YES)` from my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"]];

    #define CHECK_NULL_STRING(str) ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || !str)?@"":str

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inviteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Customization
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //Ignore this, it's for UISearchBar 
    BOOL isSearching = tableView != self.tableView;
    NSArray *arrayToUse = (isSearching ? searchResults : contactsObjects);
    id p = arrayToUse[indexPath.row];

    NSString *fName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByFirstName));
    NSString *lName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByLastName));
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", CHECK_NULL_STRING(fName), CHECK_NULL_STRING(lName)];

    _stateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0 ; i != contactsObjects.count ; i++) [_stateArray addObject:@(NO)];

    BOOL showCheckmark = [[_stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

    if (showCheckmark == YES)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = YES, and stateArray is %@",_stateArray[indexPath.row]);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = NO, and stateArray is %@",_stateArray[indexPath.row]);
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
    id object = contactsObjects[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [_stateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@(YES)];
        [selectedObjects addObject:object];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [_stateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@(NO)];
        [selectedObjects removeObject:object];
    }

    //slow-motion selection animation.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You can store [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html) as you can store only objects in NSMutableArray and bool is primitive datatype, it has method `+ (NSNumber *)numberWithBool:(BOOL)value`

Comment: Whoever down-voted this, could you please change that.

Comment: please take away the down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep track on selected items, use a `Dictionary` instead of `NSMutableArray` and keep the `indexPath.row` as **Key** and selection as curresponding **Value**.

Also instead of doing these operations with array of `BOOL's` , you can update the code as below.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * selectedRowCollection;

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    self.selectedRowCollection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
    id object = contactsObjects[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedRowCollection setObject:@"1" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]; 
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedRowCollection removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
    }

    //slow-motion selection animation.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL showCheckmark =  [[self.selectedRowCollection valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] boolValue];

    if (showCheckmark == YES)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget remove the dictionary items from dictionary while reloading a new tableview dataset.

Comment: Ok you noticed my other problem. Which is, my cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't recognize that the cell and indexPath.row is YES. In other words, the code I have up there isn't working, it's not remembering which cells **were** selected. For some reason `[_stateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@(YES)];` isn't working

Comment: Actually I'm sorry, you answered the question. This is exactly what I was asking. Why doesn't the `BOOL` way of doing it work?

Comment: Ok so when you switch to another data set, you can use the exact same `NSDictionary` to keep track of which cells are selected? @Ramshad

Comment: @Chisx you have done many mistakes. cellForRowAtIndexPath will work for each row (that means if you have 20 rows on your table view, it sould trigger 20 times). you are allocating the array every time in this delegate. so you are loosing the datas instatntly and creating new memory for thr array. So all items will be "NO" inside the array. thats it

Comment: when you switch to another data set, you have to  remove the dictionary items from dictionary. call [self.selectedRowCollection removeAllObjects]; before reloading the table. Don't do anything if you are updating any existing data's inside the table like text, image etc..

Comment: Ahh. I thought that cellForRowAtIndexPath loaded the cells each time the cells reappeared on the screen(In other words, the first time they appeared, and every appearance after). If you don't mind me asking, at which part am I reallocating the array every time? I guess what I'm asking is, what block of code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do I not need to include, that I included in the code above?(where was the unneeded reallocation)

Comment: you are reallocating the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath " _stateArray = [NSMutableArray array];" which will trigger regularly every appearance of the cell.So you will loose all the datas that you have saved earlier.

Comment: Ahhh I see it. wow. That was newly added, and wasn't working in viewDidLoad b/c it would crash and throw exception at `BOOL showCheckmark = [[_stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];` I understand completely. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hey I'm getting a 'use of undeclared identifier' for all the @%d?

Comment: ho... replace as @"%d"

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` values are wrapped with `NSNumber`, that's why you get 0's:

```
_stateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0 ; i != contactsObjects.count ; i++) [_stateArray addObject:@(NO)];

BOOL showCheckmark = [[_stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

if (showCheckmark == YES)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = YES, and stateArray is %@",[[_stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = NO, and stateArray is %@",[[_stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

`BOOL` is not object, so you cannot use the `%@` format specifier. You need to handle this manually

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Update your loop to populate `_stateArray` by

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != contactsObjects.count ; i++) {

     [_stateArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
```