# Changing the UIImage of a specific UITableViewCell when an event occurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiimageview

I have a simple `UITableViewController` with some static cells in the `UITableView`. The `UITableView` is being populated by another `UITableViewController` 's `prepareForSegue`. There are two sections to this `UITableViewController`, where the first section is a `NSMutableArray` of strings and the second section is a `NSMutableArray` containing a .txt file with strings. Some "languages" will only have one section and others will have two. There's nothing else fancy about the `UITableView`. With the use of this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/#disqus_thread, I have managed to implement custom gestures on the cell, so I can swipe the cell to mark it as favourite. I had to implement the use of the code in that tutorial to change the default behaviour from Delete to Star, as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Once a user has selected the star image, I want there to be UIImage on the cell itself, representing that this cell has been starred.

Here's some code, starting with the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
static NSString *strCellIdentifier = @"CustomLeafletVideoCell";
CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell *customCell = (CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];

self.rightUtilityButton = [NSMutableArray new];

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Favourite"])
{
    [self.rightUtilityButton sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favorites@2x.png"]];

}
else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Favourite"])
{
    [self.rightUtilityButton sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Database@2x.png"]];


}

customCell.rightUtilityButtons = self.rightUtilityButton;
customCell.delegate = self;
```

When the user taps the image in the cell, this method fires off:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        {

        self.selectedRowCollection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell *cell = (CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // We create a new NSString and assign it to the custom label's text (which is obtained from the cellForRow method)
        NSString *cellTitle = cell.customCellLabel.text;

        NSLog(@"The text is %@", cellTitle);


        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        Favourites *favourites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        favourites.title = cellTitle;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            // Error
        }


        [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];


        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I am storing the "title" in Core Data.

**Issue**

When I swipe the cell and press the star image, it doesn't load up the cell with the `UIImageView` in the designated area. The reason it doesn't is because I truly don't understand what to do.

I understand the answer is indicating that I should create a custom class and while I understand the theory behind that, I cannot understand how to actually implement this appropriately.

I've looked at this reference: [Using BOOL objects in NSMutableArray to determine cell statuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249219/using-bool-objects-in-nsmutablearray-to-determine-cell-statuses) to use a checkmark as the accessory when a cell is selected. This works, but it places a checkmark in the first section and second section on the same corresponding cell.

I've figured out I can get the exact row number and section number from `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section`, but I'm just not sure how to tackle this information at all. I could always add a `isFavourite` `BOOL` to the `Core Data` Model, but how do I actually set that in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath?`

So to conclude, and for the 250 bounty I'm putting on this question, I need to understand how:

- Set the specific `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` with the image, and
- Maintain it so that every time I come back to this `UITableViewController`, the star is on the appropriate cell

I'm kind of a newbie here, so if you're happy to help with as much information as you can, I'd really appreciate that.

Also, I'm not having issues with what to do with the Favourite after; that works - I just need to get the image onto the cell when a cell has been marked as favourite.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

**Update**

This is the code I have for setting the favourites:

```
        self.isFavourite = @(!self.isFavourite.boolValue);
```

Where `self.isFavourite` is a `NSNumber` property created on this `UITableViewController`.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    customCell.customCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.availableLeaflets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    if (self.isFavourite.boolValue)
    {
        customCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        customCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

The code here is setting the titles from the `self.availableLeaflets`. This works to set the checkmark on the cell, but the problem is, when I come back to this `UITableViewController`, the checkmark hasn't persisted on the selected cell.

Here, `self.availableLeaflets` is a `NSMutableArray` that gets populated and set from the `prepareForSegue` in the previous `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code marks all cells as favorite when a user taps on the star in one cell because you store only 1 key in the UserDefaults.

You have to store the favorite state for each cell individually. Each cell must have its own 'favorite' boolean value.

**Update:**

This is a working example on how to achieve want you want without using Core Data. I simplified the example for clarity reasons:

1. The tableview shows the title of the cell. If a cell is a favorite, it shows the checkmark accessory view.
2. To mark a cell you simply select it. (I ommitted the whole button code the keep the example simple). If you select the cell a second time it is removed from the favorites

Here's what you have to do:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "CellData.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *favoritesDict;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger context;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *language;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup the table view
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    // setup the favorites dictionary in user defaults (if it does not exist)
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"favoritesDict"] == nil) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@{} forKey:@"favoritesDict"];
    }

    // set the language of your current table view
    self.language = @"en";

    // load favorites from user defaults
    self.favoritesDict = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"favoritesDict"] mutableCopy];

}

// this method changes the favorite state of the cell at a given index path
- (void)toggleFavoriteStateForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // toggle the favorite state of the cell
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.language, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    if (self.favoritesDict[key] == nil) {
        self.favoritesDict[key] = @(1);
    } else {
        [self.favoritesDict removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

    // save the change
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.favoritesDict forKey:@"favoritesDict"];

    // reload the cell
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // add the text to your cell

    // set up favorite state
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.language, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    if (self.favoritesDict[key]) {
        // show the favorite image
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; // for this example: show checkmark
    } else {
        // hide the favorite image
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; // for this example: hide checkmark
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

// toggle the favorite state of the cell when the user selects it
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self toggleFavoriteStateForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

@end
```

This example works for tables with multiple sections. It uses a NSDictionary and stores favorited cells in a key that has the following syntax `LANGUAGE_SECTION_ROW`. To check if a cell is marked as favorite just check if there is a object for the related key in the dictionary. The actual value of that key does not matter. You just check for the key.

Just make sure that you set the language string in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks @joern - that makes sense. Please could I ask if you could put some sample code that could help me realise how to do this? I figure if I create a BOOL called favourite in the custom cell and then in this class's cellForRowAtIndexPath, I can reference that by customCell.favourite, but if I set it to YES, isn't it also marking all cells as favourite? I'm trying to figure a way to get the indexPath.row?

Comment: You cannot put that boolean value into your custom cell class because cell are not persisted by the system, the get reused when you scroll. But your table view has a data source that holds the data for the cells (like the text to display for each cell). You have to add the boolean value there.

Comment: Thanks @joern - that makes sense and I get I should put that code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath where the code is to define the text in the cells. What I'm not quite sure about is how to do that in the code; how to set the selected cell with the indexPath.

Comment: Your table view has a data source. That data source as some sort of array that holds the data for your cells (like the text it should display for a cell). Each of this array data items needs an additional boolean value `favorite` that you can set to `true` is a user taps on the star of a cell. When you fill the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you get the corresponding data item from the data array and set the image according to the `favorite` value of the item.

Comment: Dear @joern - many thanks for the reply again. I understand this part, and I'm sorry I'm just not getting how to do this. My datasource is self.availableLeaflets and self.availableLeaflets is a NSMutableArray that gets set in prepareForSegue before this UITableViewController, so the UITableViewController that calls this one that I'm working with. I am adding in the entries for the availableLeaflets in that prepareForSegue method, where I put in the titles of the cells. I'm not quite sure I understand how or where to add a bool for favourites to this same data source.

Comment: No problem. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Dear @joern - that is absolutely perfect. That helps a ton now because that actually makes so much sense and I can work through that. It'll take me time to go through that so rather than just leave this question open, this has given me enough indication on what I'd need to do and I really appreciate that. I'm storing the favourites in CoreData; funnily enough, that aspect is already working very well and the favourites get displayed elsewhere in the app through the use of the NSFRC; I thought that would have been harder than this ;)

Comment: Dear @joern - Sorry about this - I'm just not getting it. I have the custom CellData, but how do I assign a Bool to each cell. For example, I have 5 strings, how do I assign NO to the bool favourite for each of those cells and then add it to the MutableArray.

Comment: I have updated my question with all of the details and a bounty on offer as well.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Dear @joern - that's absolutely brilliant and I really appreciate you re-writing that. It made perfect sense and I'm almost there. At the moment, the reason I can't use Core Data for holding the titles of the cells (the strings) is because there are over 3000 entries and while I am happy with Core Data and the way it works to do this, I need to avoid Core Data for now. For this purpose, I have the cell showing the checkmark when selected as per your example; that's all good. The only thing I don't know is how to persist the checkmark through each launch, WITHOUT using Core Data to store that

Comment: So to clarify.. Everything works at this point really well with your code (again, thank you!).. And it shows the checkmark on the selected cell and removes it when the cell is selected again. However, I am not using Core Data anymore due to various reasons, and I need to understand how to persist the cell with that has been marked as favourite through each launch, without Core Data.

Comment: How do you persist the cell titles?

Comment: In the prepareForSegue for the UITableViewController that calls this UITableViewController, I have NSMutableArrays with the objects added in manually from a txt file. I pass the NSMutableArray to the custom setter for that NSMutableArray in this UITableViewController and use that to display the titles in the cells. It's a terrible approach, I know.. and will modify it later, but right now, just urgently need to get the Favourites persisting per cell

Comment: I changed the example so that it uses the user defaults for storage.

Comment: Thanks for the update @joern. I'm sorry I forgot to mention this in my previous comment, but I have a NSNumber (called isFavourite) declared as a property in this UITableViewController. It allows me to follow your original code regarding Core Data to set up the favourites on the cell, so in your case, does self.favouritesArray represent the NSMutableArray that I'm using to populate the table, or is it creating a NSMutableArray to hold the favourites?

Comment: I'm so sorry for just so many questions here - I really appreciate your help on this. I have updated my question at the bottom to show the code and issue I'm facing (and it looks like the final issue to me). While I understand your code regarding the NSUserDefaults, I'm not sure I understand why objects were being added and removed from the method that set the favourite state.

Comment: In your code you only have 1 property for the favorite state of ALL cells. That cannot work. In my answer i have an array called `favoritesArray`. When a cell is marked as favorite I add its `indexPath.row` to the array. So the `favoritesArray` contains the `indexPath.row` of all favorited cells. If a user removes the favorite state, the `indexPath.row` of that cell is removed from the array. So the array only contains the cell that are favorited. So you can check if your cell is favorited by checking if the cell's `indexPath.row` is part of the array.

Comment: Ah that's perfect Joern - thanks very much and that makes sense. I just have two remaining questions (I'm sorry!). How do I target and save the specific row in the section to the array? Right now, it takes the checkmark on row 1 in section 0 for example, but then it also places the checkmark in row 1 of section 1 (there will in some cases be two sections and in other cases, just 1).

Comment: And the second question is.. I'm preparing the data in the prepareForSegue of the previous UITableViewController; the user may save a favourite in the "English" selection in the prepareForSegue, but not in the German. Is that where I'd put some logic to figure out which cell of which language is a favourite, etc? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have updated my answer. It now handles language and sections.

Comment: that is absolutely perfect. You've helped me so much with this and I wish I could offer you more than the 250 bounty here. I really appreciate it and with this last update, everything's working as expected with the languages, sections, etc. Thanks so much again!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help you out.

Comment: Hi @joern - I hope you're well.. I'm having an extended issue related to this question - it's just extending the functionality again and as you provided the answer here, I thought you may be best suited. Should I create another question and link it here, if you're able and willing to take a look at that?

Comment: Hi @amitsbajaj. Please create another question and link it here. I'm a bit busy at the moment, but maybe i find the time to look at it.

Comment: Thanks so much @joern, I really appreciate it. Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824172/consistent-use-of-uiimageview-on-the-uitableviewcells-in-different-uitableviewco for whenever you have the time. I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @joern - I've just put a bounty on the question as well.