# NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1] error with CoreData and NSFRC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple application that is a two tabbed `UITabBarController`. The first Tab is called `Languages` and it contains a list of hard coded Languages in the app. In the `prepareForSegue` method, I am populating a list of Leaflets and Videos for that language by `NSMutableArray` and passing that successfully over to a new `UITableViewController` called `LeafletsAndVideos`. Some languages have Leaflets and Videos and some have just Leaflets, where Leaflets are in Section 0 and Videos are in Section 1.

With reference to this question: [Changing the UIImage of a specific UITableViewCell when an event occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420341/changing-the-uiimage-of-a-specific-uitableviewcell-when-an-event-occurs/33420553?noredirect=1#33420553), I have set up the use of "Favourting" specific cells in the `LeafetsAndVideos`. Through the use of `Core Data`, I am taking the title of the cell that was favourited, adding it to the `Core Data` model. The reason I do this is because the second tab is called `Favourites` and through the use of `NSFetchedResultsController`, I am populating this `UITableView` with any cells that have been "Favourited".

That park works really well.

The problem now is that when in the `LeafletsAndVideos` `UITableView`, I favourite a cell and it appears in the `Favourites` tab straight away through the use of NSFRC on the `FavouritesTableViewController`, but if I want to unfavorite the same cell, I want that to be deleted from the `Favourites` tab.

**Issue**

The issue is that when I unfavorite a cell, it is just added to the `Favourites` tab again.

For the sake of clarity, when I say "Favourite", let's say I am tapping on the cell (`didSelectCell`) and so when I tap on it again, it unfavorites.

The `LeafletsAndTable` `UITableView` has no reference to the `NSFRC` and it doesn't really need one because the cells are being populated by the `NSMutableArray's` set in the Languages `UITableView` (I totally understand I can just use `Core Data` for the titles, but that's complicated in this particular setup - `Core Data` is just being used as a mechanism to detect the titles of the Favourited cells).

Within my `LeafletAndVideo` `UITableView`, I have the following code when setting up the `Favourites`:

```
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell *cell = (CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString *cellTitle = cell.customCellLabel.text;
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];            
        Favourites *favourites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        favourites.title = cellTitle;
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
        if (self.favoritesDict[key] == nil) {
            self.favoritesDict[key] = @(1);
        } else {
            [self.favoritesDict removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.favoritesDict forKey:@"favoritesDict"];
NSError *error = nil;

        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            // Error
        }

        [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

**Issue**

With the code above, when unfavouriting a cell, it gets added again to the Favourites tab (which is fair enough because I'm not doing any deleting here).

So in the else statement of that code, I tried something. I remove the object from the dictionary but I am also calling the `Favourites` tab and the method `completeFetchedResults`:

```
        if (self.favoritesDict[key] == nil) {
            self.favoritesDict[key] = @(1);
        } else {
            [self.favoritesDict removeObjectForKey:key];
            FavouritesTableViewController *favTab = [[FavouritesTableViewController alloc] init];
            [favTab completeFetchedResults];
            [favTab moreButtonPressed:indexPath];

        }
```

This method is simply calling the fetch on the `NSFRC`.

```
- (void)completeFetchedResults
{
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        //exit(-1);
    }

}
```

I am then calling the method to delete the object by passing it the `indexPath`:

```
- (void)moreButtonPressed:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        // Error
    }

}
```

When I run this, select a cell, it favourites it (as expected) and gets added to the `Favourites` tab. When I select the cell again (to remove the favourite), it crashes out with this error:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
```

When I place an exception breakpoint, it crashes at:

```
if (![context save:&error])
{
    // Error
}
```

In the `moreButtonPressed` method.

I'm not too sure how to fix this, but the desired effect is that when I select the cell, it favourites it (working) and when I select the cell again, it:

1) Deletes the object from the Favourites tab (not working)

Any guidance would really be appreciated.

**Stack Trace Update**

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c588f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bc7adeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c477b14 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 164
3   Street Parchar                      0x000000010b5e8b37 -[FavouritesTableViewController moreButtonPressed:] + 151
4   Street Parchar                      0x000000010b5f2386 -[LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController swipeableTableViewCell:didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:] + 1158
5   Street Parchar                      0x000000010b5e44d5 -[SWTableViewCell rightUtilityButtonHandler:] + 213
6   UIKit                               0x000000010d1e194f _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 153
7   UIKit                               0x000000010d1ddfc1 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 162
8   UIKit                               0x000000010d1dbfbe -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 843
9   UIKit                               0x000000010d1e4283 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke898 + 79
10  UIKit                               0x000000010d1e4121 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 342
11  UIKit                               0x000000010d1d1bdd _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2634
12  UIKit                               0x000000010cd6f9c0 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
13  UIKit                               0x000000010cd70bf6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
14  UIKit                               0x000000010cd202fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
15  UIKit                               0x000000010ccfaabf _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4b5011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4aaf3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4aa3f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4a9e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111165ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x000000010cd0030d UIApplicationMain + 171
22  Street Parchar                      0x000000010b5dfedf main + 111
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001104ae92d start + 1
24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**Update 2**

Including the `fetchedResultsController` in the `FavouritesTab`

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    NSPredicate *d = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != nil"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:d];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:NO];


    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe - I've just updated the question and placed the Stack Trace at the bottom - I hope that's what you require

Comment: After removing the managed item reload the whole table data rather than one index path to keep table view and data source in sync.

Comment: First I suggest change line  [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]; to  separate lines - id object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object] to find out which line is failing first. Looks like "self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:" though. Looks like your method, can you show that too?

Comment: Hi Vadian - unfortunately, that kept the same crash at the same point. @PooLaS - thanks for feedback. I have updated the question with the fetchedResultsController. I tried to separate the line, but I'm not sure what the "object" is in deleteObject:

Comment: @amitsbajaj id object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @PooLaS oh sorry, yeah missed that! It crashed even with that code and it's crashing on if (![context save:&error]) in the moreButtonPressed method with the exception breakpoint.

Comment: Why is using core data for everything complicated for you / this case?

Comment: Hi @Wain - I have about 3000 entries which have already been added via NSMutableArray before using Core Data. I'm so close to finishing this app that I don't want to rewrite the entries into Core Data (though if that's a way to make this work, I might just have to?)

Comment: @PooLaS - Do you have any thoughts with this?

Comment: How is `FavouritesTableViewController` related to the current view controller? Why do you create a new instance?

Comment: Thanks @vadian - the FavouritesTableViewController is separate from the current viewController (where the cell is being added and then removed as a Favourite). The FavouritesTableViewController uses NSFRC to list the favourites. Essentially, I want to make sure when I unfavorite something (the else statement that calls the FavouritesTableViewController), I want to remove that object from Core Data

Comment: Is FavouritesTableViewController created in Interface Builder? Is it visible when a cell is selected? I suspect that the newly created instance of FavouritesTableViewController is not connected to a corresponding object in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks @vadian - it is created in Interface Builder. The Favourites UITableView is working in that when I favourite a cell from the LeafletsAndVideo, it gets added to Core Data and if I go to the Favourites tab, through the use of Core Data and NSFRC, it is showing the title of the tab that I favourited in the LeafletsAndVideo. If I go back to the LeafletsAndVideo and unfavorite the cell, it causes the crash. My desired effect is the title of the cell that I unfavorite, be removed from Core Data and therefore the Favourites tab. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If it's created in Interface Builder you need the reference as an `IBOutlet` or via `prepareForSegue`. Delete the appropriate Core Data item also in `LeafletsAndTable`, then go to the Favourites controller and fetch the data in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Is there anyway @vadian we can possibly chat about this on the SO chat? LeafletsAndVideos and FavouritesTableView are two separate UITableViewControllers in a UITabBar, so they don't segue to each other. If I select a cell in the LeafletsAndVideo, it adds the title of that cell to Core Data. The FavouritesTableView is set up using NSFRC and when an item is favourited, it is added to the FavouritesTableView. If I remove the Favourite from the same cell on the LeafletsAndVideos, it's supposed to also remove the same entry from the FavouritesTableView. That's not happening at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95571/discussion-between-vadian-and-amitsbajaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the new instance of `FavouritesTableViewController` which has no connection to the corresponding object in Interface Builder.

You have to perform all Core Data related tasks in the `LeafletsAndVideos` controller like this code

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row]; 
if (self.favoritesDict[key] == nil) { 
    self.favoritesDict[key] = @(1); 
    Favourites *favourites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
    favourites.title = cellTitle; 
} 
else { 
    [self.favoritesDict removeObjectForKey:key]; 
    NSError *error; 
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext: context]; 
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", cellTitle]; 
    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
    if (error == nil && items.count) { 
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = items[0]; 
        [context deleteObject:managedObject]; 
    } 
}
```

When you switch to the Favourites tab and perform a fetch in `viewWillAppear` the data will be displayed correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much @vadian - this worked perfectly. I wasn't fully understanding the concept in my head and with your clear and accurate help, this issue now works and I'm so happy. Thanks again!

Comment: p.s. It says I can only award the bounty in 19 hours, so I'll make sure to do that as soon as I can!