# Consistent use of UIImageView on the UITableViewCells in different UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a simple 4-tab `UITabBarController`, with each tab consistent of a `UITableViewController`. The first Tab is called `Videos`, the second is `Languages`, the third is `Favourites` and the fourth is `Leaflets`. The `Videos` Tab contains a list of languages (about 6) and when a cell is clicked on, a `segue` is performed to show the available videos of that language. The `Languages` tab is a list of all Languages in the app. When a cell is clicked on, the available Leaflets and Videos for that language are shown. The `Favourites` is populated using Core Data (I will come back to this) and finally, the `Leaflets` tab is a list of languages; when you click on a language, you see leaflets available in that language.

The data, content of cells, the leaflets and the videos are all populated via `NSMutableArray`s in the `prepareForSegue`. The app is working very well.

With guidance from this question: [Changing the UIImage of a specific UITableViewCell when an event occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420341/changing-the-uiimage-of-a-specific-uitableviewcell-when-an-event-occurs/33420553?noredirect=1#comment55387062_33420553), I am able to tap on a cell in the `Languages` tab and it does two things:

1) Adds a star `UIImageView` to the cell

2) Adds the title of that cell to Core Data

The `Favourites` tab is using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate it's `UITableViewCell`s with the titles of the cells that have been favourited.

That part is working really well.

**Issue**

However, I would now like to implement consistency. What I mean by this is, if the user selects "English" in the `Languages` tab and favourites a video called "3 Facts", when they go to the `Videos` tab and click on English, the "3 Facts" `cell` should have a favourite on it.

The `Languages` tab is the only `UITableViewController` that after showing the Languages, shows a `UITableViewController` with sections with Leaflets on section 0 and Videos on section 1. If the user goes to the `Videos` tab and selects a Language, it only contains one section.

This is the code that is currently doing the favouriting:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell *selectedCell = (CustomLeafletVideoTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // We create a new NSString and assign it to the custom label's text (which is obtained from the cellForRow method)
    NSString *cellTitle = selectedCell.customCellLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"The text is %@", cellTitle);
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    if (self.favoritesDict[key] == nil)
    {
        self.favoritesDict[key] = @(1);
        Favourites *favourites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        favourites.title = cellTitle;

    }
    else
    {

        [self.favoritesDict removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.favoritesDict forKey:@"favoritesDict"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        // Error
    }
    [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

The `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` contains:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"favoritesDict"] == nil) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@{} forKey:@"favoritesDict"];
}

// load favorites from user defaults
self.favoritesDict = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"favoritesDict"] mutableCopy];
```

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` contains:

```
if(indexPath.section==0)
{
    customCell.customCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.availableLeaflets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    if (self.favoritesDict[key]) {
        // show the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        // hide the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = YES;
    }
}
else
{
    customCell.customCellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(8, 20, 100, 40);
    customCell.customCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.availableVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    if (self.favoritesDict[key]) {
        // show the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        // hide the favorite image
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = YES;
    }

}
```

The `NSString *key` has a role to play here because it is obtaining the correct section and row. When I copy this code over to the `Videos` tab, the favourite does not exist on the same title that it does with the `Languages` tab.

Ultimately, consistency is the important thing here. The user may favourite something from the Videos tab or Languages tab, but either way, the same "title" should be favourited in the other tab.

**Update**

Based on the comment of using NSUserDefaults, I have added some code. Firstly, in the LanguagesTab, I have added some code in the method that does the favouriting:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
if (self.favoritesDict[key] == nil)
{
    self.favoritesDict[key] = @(1);
    Favourites *favourites = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    favourites.title = cellTitle;


    NSString *valueToSave = cellTitle;
    NSLog(@"The valuetosave is %@", cellTitle);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"starredName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}
```

Back in the `VideosTab`, in the `cellForRow`, I have:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld_%ld", self.selectedLanguage, (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
if (self.favoritesDict[key]) {
    // show the favorite image
    customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
} else {
    // hide the favorite image
    customCell.customCellImage.hidden = YES;
}

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"starredName"];

if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"# 3 The One Show"])
{
    NSLog(@"Display star");
    customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Don't display star"); 
}
```

This works to some extent. For example, I selected a cell in the Languages tab called # 3 The One Show and when I come back to the `Videos` tab, it does detect that in the if statement and it runs the NSLog to display a star. It then displays the star. However, the issue is, it shows the star on EVERY cell. I want it to only show a star on the cell that has the text "# 3 The One Show".

I tried:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"starredName"];

if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"# 3 The One Show"])
{
    if ([customCell.customCellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"# 3 The One Show"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Display star");
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;

    }

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Don't display star"); 
}
```

This looks like it's working and now showing and not-showing the cell. However, this works with 1 value in the savedValue. In the cellForRow, if I have:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"starredName"];

if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"# 3 The One Show"])
{
    NSLog(@"Display star");
    NSLog(@"The cell is %@", customCell.customCellLabel.text);
    if ([customCell.customCellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"# 3 The One Show"])
    {
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;

    }

}
else if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"Real Talk - Sangat TV discussion #TruthAbout1984"])
{
    NSLog(@"Display the star yo");
    NSLog(@"The title is %@", customCell.customCellLabel.text);
    if ([customCell.customCellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Real Talk - TV discussion"])
    {
        customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO;
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Don't display star"); 
}
```

It only shows the star on the latest entry to the `savedValue` `NSUserDefaults` and because I have 1000+ entries, it won't be efficient to actually create different keys for each different entry, etc.

Now, because my `Favourites` `UITableViewController` is being populated by Core Data and the UITableViewCells are being populated by `favourites.title`, could I do something with that? So, I already have the values of the titles that have been favourited, but isn't there a way to translate that in the Videos tab. Perhaps do a fetch request to get the titles, etc? I just need some guidance with this.

I have this code:

```
Favourites *favourite = nil;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Favourites"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != nil"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *favs = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


if (!favs)
{
    NSLog(@"Nothing to see here");
    // Handle Error
}
else
{
    // If the object exists, just return it
    //        favourite = [favs lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Number of objects %lu", [favs count]);


    NSString *elements;
    for (elements in favs)
    {

        NSLog(@"Elements %@", elements);
    }
    NSLog(@"Things to see here");
}

NSLog(@"The Favourites are %@", favourite.title);
```

This is more just stabbing in the dark though - I'm not sure how to return all of the objects of the Array and then to place the image on that cell with customCell.customCellImage.hidden = NO, etc.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: just store the value for the language in "[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]" and then call to this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath to then process an if/then statement that sets one image vs another

Comment: Thanks @Larcerax - that makes sense - just so I'm not missing anything ,please could I ask if you could post a potential solution for that, especially for the code in the cellForRow?

Comment: Yeah, let me see what i can put together

Comment: Thank you - really appreciate it!

Comment: Dear @Larcerax - sorry, was just wondering if you had a chance to look into this question to provide a bit of sample code?

Comment: @Larcerax - I think I may have it working - I've just updated the question.

Comment: I have managed to fix this issue with the use of FetchRequests from Core Data, however, I need to assign a bounty, so if you can provide your take on it, I can provide the bounty.

Comment: First off, on the second usage of standard user defaults, don't use defaults to story anything but things like "overall app preference data" like "preferred language", "users gender" , etc. NSUserDefaults is going to be too inefficient to use for storing table cell info. Secondly, to assign custom values like "starred" cells vs "unstarred cells", this is where things get a little complicated due to how UITableView's datasource works. If you want to do this the most efficient way, then you read the data from arrays and make starred cells vs unstarred cells in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: If you want to get even more complex to do stars live while the user is inside the tableview, then you will need to start implementing even more logic on this cells so they don't all stay selected, the reason they continue to stay selected is due to the "reuse" of tableviewcells. In this case, the way I do this, is add a new field to the array of tableviewcell data that keeps a selector or count of something in the tableview array and then at cellForRowAtIndexPath, I just read from this custom array dictionary.

Comment: Another idea, and this is for the increase in performance that can come from this, is to use 1 NSMutableArray for the main cell data, and then keep mirrors of the NSMutableArray using NSMutableSets. This is how you would implement a super fast instant search on the tableview items. Even more complex, if you want to keep the NSMutableSets in an ordered fashion that matches the index of the NSMutableArray, then you should just use an NSMutableArray, unless you think you may need an NSMutableOrderedSet, but but ordered sets are less performant, in alot of cases, than just a NSMutableArray.

Comment: One additional implication to think about, if you want to make sure that you don't have data duplication while tracking a bunch of different array dictionary objects, then use the NSMutableArray for the main cell data info, but then always pull in the data that you need for the TableView using an NSMutableSet, and then repopulate the NSMutableArray with the objects in the NSMutableSet, then reorder the NSMutableArray however you like. This is some complex stuff here for you, probably, but this is just how tableViews work. There's no easy way to make them custom unless you juggle sets & arrays

Comment: @amitsbajaj can you please upload screen shots step by step after that i can easily help you in this

Comment: Dear @Larcerax - could you write an answer for this question please? Just based on your last comment and then I can provide the bounty.